# Get Cookie with HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get Cookie from HTTP get request with HttpWebReqquest object in c# but I don't find it.
if i execute the next http get reuqest in the browser:

[https://www.lefrecce.it/msite/api/solutions?origin=Milano Centrale&destination=Roma Termini&arflag=A&adate=25/01/2021 0:00:00&atime=10&adultno=1&childno=0&direction=A&frecce=false&onlyRegional=false](https://www.lefrecce.it/msite/api/solutions?origin=Milano%20Centrale&destination=Roma%20Termini&arflag=A&adate=16/01/2021%200:00:00&atime=8&adultno=1&childno=0&direction=A&frecce=false&onlyRegional=false)

you can see clearly that there are 3 Set-Cookies:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDsLt.png)

but when I execute it with HttpWebRequest:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    res = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

I can see in the headers only 2 cookies and the third one is missing:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vy7V.png)

so how can I get this cookie from?

thanks.

Comment: Look at the browsers *request* headers, there will be some (user-agent/accept/any other existing cookies) that are not sent with an HttpWebRequest request unless you explicitly add them.

Comment: but why do i have to send it in my HttpWebRequest? i didnt sent them when i execute the url in the browser...

Comment: Getting the cookies from a response and adding them to the next request is what a browser does. If you use an `HttpWebRequest` (or the respective way in any programming language) you need to take care of all the data sent to a server yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this in net5 and I see three cookies: [image: Set-Cookie HTTP header]